# email is not coming in facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

This is login system in facebook php sdk,what happens it asks for basic permissions then when a user permits through his facebook account it stores his facebook id and email and then shows this fbid and email in the index through session ,but it is not working properly though fbid comes nut email is not coming it is showing blank

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 require_once("autoload.php"); 
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
 require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
 require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
 require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
 require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
 require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );    
 use Facebook\FacebookSession; use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest; use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
 use Facebook\FacebookSDKException; use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
 use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException; use Facebook\GraphObject;
 // init app with app id and secret
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(     '     332325566667346','30adsfsdf7sdf87df6s7df87sdf76dsfd16' );
 // login helper with redirect_uri
 $helper = new           FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/bb/fbconfig.php'     );
 try {
   $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
 } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
   // When Facebook returns an error
 } catch( Exception $ex ) {
 }
 // see if we have a session
 if ( isset( $session ) ) {
   $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
   $response = $request->execute();
   $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
     $email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');          
   echo $email;
 } else {
   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
  header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking for the email permission in your login process:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl

Side note: Use the autoloader OR countless require statements, not both ;) (Autoloader would be the smart option though).

Comment: but it does not work if i only give only  the autoloader

Comment: well, something else may be wrong then, but point of the autoloader is that you don´t need all those countless require statements ;)

Comment: if I remove "require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');" then it shows the error "Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bb\fbconfig.php on line 23" how to solve it

Comment: search for the error with google and you will find plenty of results. anyway, the point of this thread is to get the email, the comment about the autoloader was just a side note.